# Need help to understand this sentence:

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading an article where there was a breakup story of a couple. Somebody commented with feedback and said in the middle of a long explanation that:

```
It requires nuance based on your individual dynamic with her.
```

Can somebody help me understand the meaning of this sentence in the context of relation between individuals? More specifically, what does 'nuance' and 'dynamic' refer to in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Nuance* refers to the subtle, often complex differences between a given situation and other, similar situations.

*Individual dynamic* is essentially used here as a synonym for *relationship*.  The term feels a bit awkward to me, so I wouldn't necessarily use it.  The notion is that relationships between people are constantly changing, so the subtle, complex differences may also change.

There isn't enough context here to be certain, but I expect previous sentences in the explanation attempted to impart advice in more-general terms.  This subsequent sentence further advises that the matter is more complicated than the general terms, and that you must adjust based, depending on your circumstances.

Essentially, the sentence is warning that *you* may need to apply any previous statements differently, depending on the relationship *you* have with *her*.

Comment: Great explanation. Much obliged.